# Difference between @EnableAutoConfiguration vs @SpringBootConfiguration ( @AutoConfigurationPackage vs @Configuration )

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I know that when we annotate a java class as `@SpringBootApplication` we will have internally annotations `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@SpringBootConfiguration` but i'm confused what is the difference between them.

I am very much new to spring boot, Can someone please elaborate on this.

Comment: The difference between which?

Answer (score 3):

> public @interface SpringBootConfiguration
>
> Indicates that a class provides Spring Boot application
>   @Configuration. Can be used as an alternative to the Spring's standard
>   @Configuration annotation so that configuration can be found
>   automatically (for example in tests).

from: [SpringBootConfiguration docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringBootConfiguration.html)

> public @interface EnableAutoConfiguration
>
> Enable auto-configuration of the Spring Application Context,
>   attempting to guess and configure beans that you are likely to need.

from: [EnableAutoConfiguration docs](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.1.7.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfiguration.html)

So what is the difference?

**@SpringBootConfiguration** annotation tells us that a class is a configuration class, and **@EnableAutoConfiguration** automatically configures the Spring application based on its included jar files.

Comment: I guess @EnableAutoConfiguration does not configure base on jar files but based on spring.factoris file

Answer (score 0):

it is meta annotation @SpringBootApplication will have other annotations

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.java

if @SpringBootApplication is not there applications need to use other annotations on Main class