# Why @EnableAutoConfiguration when we already have @Conditonal and @Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Why do we need `@EnableAutoConfiguration` when we already have `@Conditional` on `@Configuration` annotated classes. Aren't these 2 annotations self sufficient to scan the libs on the classpath and create beans? Why do we need an extra `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58916647/difference-between-enableautoconfiguration-vs-springbootconfiguration-autoc

Answer (score 3):

**The [@EnableAutoConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfiguration.html) annotation enables Spring Boot to auto-configure the application context. Therefore, it automatically creates and registers beans based on both the included jar files in the classpath and the beans defined by us.**

For example, when we define the spring-boot-starter-web dependency in our classpath, Spring boot auto-configures Tomcat and Spring MVC. However, this auto-configuration has less precedence in case we define our own configurations.

**The package of the class declaring the [@EnableAutoConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfiguration.html) annotation is considered the default.** Therefore, we should always apply the [@EnableAutoConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfiguration.html) annotation in the root package so that every sub-package and class can be examined:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class EmployeeApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(EmployeeApplication.class, args);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Secondly, if you have bootstrapped your application with Spring Boot, it will have [@SpringBootApplication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html) annotation which is equivalent to using [@Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html), [@EnableAutoConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfiguration.html), and [@ComponentScan](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html), so you wouldn't need to explicitly add [@EnableAutoConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfiguration.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the auto configuration example that you gave above, can't it be done using just Configuration and Conditonal? Initialise the beans defined in the Configuration class only if the condition defined in the Conditional is satisfied?